# Amazon Instance Hung Up (Any Hope?)

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, amazon-web-services

I have very, very few users.

I was scrapping some data today but that's usually not a problem. I've attached a screenshot of my instance stats.

Everything has[image] normalized and the instance is still hanging. Do I have any hope here?

Comment: Which OS are you using ?

Comment: Using Ubuntu 10.4

Comment: When it hangs can you still use ssh to access it ? If you can what does top have to say ?

Comment: I can't ssh into the instance, which is clearly not a good sign

Comment: Try restarting it, if that doesn't work, detach the EBS-block and start a new instance. Don't get attached to your EC2-instance :-)

Comment: If I restart it I'll lose all the temporary files right? Like my entire Lamp Stack?  I'm deploying Django, I don't have an AMI setup and it's a massive pain to recreate the Django Environment

Comment: As it is right now, you have no disk activity and can't ssh to it.  I don't think you can salvage anything it without restarting.

Comment: It is a Christmas miracle.  I rebooted her and she somehow or other came back to life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon EC2 instances should be thought of as temporary, we have about 100 running and about 10% die every week, we just kill them off and start again. Just create a new instance from the EBS image (You created an EBS image right? ;) ).

At first I thought this was a bit odd for so many instances to fail on such a regular basis but I contacted AWS support and they said pretty much what I said above. Infact I don't think I've ever had an instance running for longer than a month without it failing (Although we do hammer all our instances, they're on 100% CPU pretty-much all the time)

Comment: This is really a useful point of view.  I felt like a tool for blowing up an instance without any real traffic.  Now I know that it just happens sometimes. Thanks