# AWS (Amazon) EC2 - instance basic question

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm starting with EC2 with my free tier. I was wondering if, let's say, I put into the server a website and it uses too much processor (more than 1.6 GHz), too much RAM... it will invoke another instance automatically or may I need to program it somehow?

I'm using Ubuntu Lucid (standard AMI) for this.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless you tell it to. An EC2 instance is just an instance, it has no other logic or system behind it. If you need auto-scaling this can ether be achieved by writing your own software to interact with the API or using Cloudwatch, a service from Amazon that lets you specify under what conditions servers should auto-scale up and down. Without a system like that you can launch one instance and, no matter how much CPU and ram it uses it will never scale up beyond the one instance. Do bear in mind though that Amazon EC2 micro instances are not expected for more than a few weeks* so it will most likely crash. You can set up cloudwatch to make sure at least one instance is always running so when it does fail a new instance will be brought up automatically.

*See my post on [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/273792/amazon-instance-hung-up-any-hope/273827)